# Magento - Transaction E-Mails - Variables

Tags: magento, variables, invoice

is it somehow possible to use {{var invoice.increment_id}} in the creditmemo e-mails? It don't work if I do so...

```
<p><strong>Bestellnummer:</strong> {{var order.increment_id}}</p>
<p><strong>Datum:</strong> {{var creditmemo.created_at}}</p>
<p><strong>Rechnung:</strong> {{var invoice.increment_id}}</p>
<p>Liebe(r) {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()}},<br/><br/>
```

Doesn't work. Does someone has a hint for me? Thanks!

EDIT
Is that correct? 
Edit the class Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Creditmemo and adding:

```
//Get Invocie from order Object 
        if ($order->hasInvoices()) {
            // "$_eachInvoice" is each of the Invoice object of the order "$order"
            foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $_eachInvoice) {
                $invoice = $_eachInvoice->getIncrementId();
            }

            //$invoice = $order->getInvoiceCollection();
        }
```

aswell as

```
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
                'order'      => $order,
                'creditmemo' => $this,
                'comment'    => $comment,
                'invoice'    => $invoice,
                'billing'    => $order->getBillingAddress()
            )
        );
```

and afterwards calling the variable {{var invoice}} in my email template?
But it doesn't show, what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rewrite `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Creditmemo` model in your module and add needed logic to `sendUpdateEmail()` method to get invoice object in credit memo email templates.

Answer (score 0):

See my frist post. I got it right. Thanks to Zyava.
The problem was, you have to place this code one method above the sendUpdateEMail(), in sendEmail().

Thanks!